# Can I access a method inside another method?

Tags: ruby, methods, arguments, private, argument-passing

Can I access a method inside another method

```
 def one(a)
   if a < 10
       two() 
   else
       print "ITs passed in first function ONE"
   end
 end

 def two(b)
   if b < 10
       print "Both function failed"
   else
       print "ITs passed in second function TWO"
   end
 end

 puts one(5)
 puts two(15)
```

If I run this program I get an error

```
 test4.rb:9:in `two': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
```

Comment: Read the error message carefully.

Comment: at `two()` - `two` wants one argument

Comment: Yeah i dont understand that could you please elobarate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you got isn't because you can't use the other method. It's because the argument you passed  don't match the argument that the method expects.

Specifically, the method `two` expects one argument, while you are passing it zero with `two()`.

Change it to:

```
 def one(a)
   if a < 10
       two(a)   #<--here
   else
 #...
```

Comment: It is correct but i dont want to use two(a) there i want to take two() to next function with some other argument.i tried two(b) but it throws test4.rb:5:in `one': undefined local variable or method `b' for main:Object (NameError)

Comment: i want this  puts two(15) to be in the two()

Comment: Just remember `two` expects one argument, pass whatever you need.

Answer (score -2):

You dont need to call both methods at the driver code. Use an instance variable for b and just call one function. If you prefer change the "print" for "return" inside the methods.

Comment: This is not an attempt to answer the question. Please the comment system instead to make one-line suggestions. Welcome to Stackoverflow.